# creating a fragment hit counter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a really basic app that has three fragments - fragments a,b and c, each of these fragments contains a piece of text that reads "I have been visited " + tallyVariable + " this many times".

I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way of doing it as I am new to app development and fairly new to the java language, but have attempted to give it a go.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    //tally variables
    public int numSwipes = 0;
    public int numSwipes2 = 0;
    public int numSwipes3 = 0;


    ViewPager viewPager = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    // reference to MainActivity and variables

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    int fragNumSwipes = mainActivity.numSwipes;
    int fragNumSwipes2 = mainActivity.numSwipes2;
    int fragNumSwipes3 = mainActivity.numSwipes3;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    //@Override

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(i==0)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            fragNumSwipes++;
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            fragNumSwipes2++;
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            fragNumSwipes3++;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        if(position==0)
        {
            return "tab 1";
        }
        if(position==1)
        {
            return "tab 2";
        }
        if(position==2)
        {
            return "tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

below is the code for one of the fragments (code for the rest of the fragments is identical).

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    }

    // MyAdapter adapterVariables = new MyAdapter();

}
```

I have commented out the above variable declaration "adapterVariables", but when it is active, it will not let me create a reference to the MyAdapter class where the tally variables now exist? what am I missing, I think it expects something between the parenthesis?

Comment: `code for the rest of the fragments is identical` - then you should create base fragment and make your further fragments extend it instead

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` this does **not** create a reference to your `MainActivity`! The same goes for your fragments code. You are creating **new** instances of your classes. You can pass references in your constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` this does not create a reference to your `MainActivity`! The same goes for your fragments code. You are creating new instances of your classes. You can pass references in your constructors. But for your idea, you won't need this. Below, you can find a corrected version, if you have questions about it, feel free to ask!

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //tally variables
    private int numSwipes = 0;
    private int numSwipes2 = 0;
    private int numSwipes3 = 0;

    ViewPager viewPager = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));

         //instead of increasing the number in the adapter, add a listener, since this is a better place to do it.
         viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        numSwipes++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        numSwipes2++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        numSwipes3++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {    
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        if(position==0)
        {
            return "tab 1";
        }
        if(position==1)
        {
            return "tab 2";
        }
        if(position==2)
        {
            return "tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```